# Googling DAL & DAO returns only C# .NET related results – Does a DAL/DAO type pattern exist in Java?

Tags: java, database

The subject line says it all.
Googling DAL & DAO returns only C# .NET related results.
Is there a DAL/DAO equivalent pattern in the Java world?
Are there any reference implementations available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it applies to Java as well: [Don't Repeat The DAO!](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao.html)

Have a look at Fowler's [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420).  [Core J2EE Patterns](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/) also refers to DAO.

It'd be interesting to check the dates on your C#/.NET references.  I'd bet that the idea started on the Java side and was adopted later by .NET.  Microsoft probably had another persistence technology that was their "best practice".  If I recall correctly, VB used to tie UI elements closely to columns, without an intermediate layer in-between to separate the view from the database.

Answer (score 1):

The patterns [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) and [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Access_Object) are not language specific. Using them is good style in Java, too.

The [Springframework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/dao.html) provides a nice implementation of DAOs.